# Fill within curves

Tags: plotting, filling

[image]

```
p[x_, left_, right_] := HeavisideTheta[x - left] HeavisideTheta[right - x]

Plot[{(1400 + 200 x) p[x, 0, 0.77], 
   3460 x p[x, 0, 0.36], 
   (1172 + 214 x) p[x, 0.36, 0.77]},
  {x, 0, 0.77}]
```

I have used above code to create the plot. I tried filling curve but I require it to be fill as marked in figure.

Answer (score 4):

Here  is one way to do it.

```
p[x_, left_, right_] :=  HeavisideTheta[x - left] HeavisideTheta[right - x]        

    Show[Plot[{(1400 + 200 x) p[x, 0, 0.77], 
       3460 x p[x, 0, 0.36], (1172 + 214 x) p[x, 0.36, 0.77]}, {x, 0, 
       0.36}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, PlotRange -> All], 
     Plot[{(1400 + 200 x) p[x, 0, 0.77], 
       3460 x p[x, 0, 0.36], (1172 + 214 x) p[x, 0.36, 0.77]}, {x, 0.36, 
       0.77}, Filling -> {1 -> {3}}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With

```
p[x_, left_, right_] := UnitStep[x - left] UnitStep[right - x]

f1 = (1400 + 200 #) p[#, 0, 0.77] &;
f2 = 3460 # p[#, 0, 0.36] &;
f3 = (1172 + 214 #) p[#, 0.36, 0.77] &;
```

How about

```
Plot[{f1@x, If[f2@x >= f3@x, f2@x, f3@x]}, {x, 0, 0.77}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image]

Or

```
Plot[{f1@x, If[f2@x >= f3@x, f2@x, f3@x], f2@x, f3@x}, {x, 0, 0.77}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, Exclusions -> All]
```

[image]

It's better to use `UnitStep` instead of `HeavisideTheta`, becasue with the former one gets a simple derivative (and the discountinuity can be easily located):

[image]

while one get a messy output for the latter:

[image]

`FunctionDomain[the f functions, t]` also don't work with `HeavisideTheta`, but yield `True` for the `UnitStep` case.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea how to get rid of the vertical line in the second plot?

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap the second and third functions with `ConditionalExpression[#, # > 0]&`

```
p[x_, left_, right_] := HeavisideTheta[x - left] HeavisideTheta[right - x]

Plot[{(1400 + 200 x) p[x, 0, 0.77], 
  ConditionalExpression[#, # > 0] &[3460 x p[x, 0, 0.36]], 
  ConditionalExpression[#, # > 0] &[(1172 + 214 x) p[x, 0.36, 0.77]]}, 
 {x, 0, 0.77}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Orange}, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False,  
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, LightBlue}, 1 -> {{3}, LightBlue}}]
```

[image]